# How to unset a flag in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am using the following code to disable editing of a cell in a `QTableWidget`.

```
ui->tableWidget_1->item(row,col)->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsSelectable|Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
```

This works fine. I don't understand how to undo this i.e. how do I make the cell editable again?

I've tried calling the function again in case that toggles it. I've tried calling the same function but with a `~` in front of the flags as seen elsewhere. I'm not sure if I really understand how flags work in Qt.

Comment: Please, have a look at Qt doc. [`Qt::ItemFlag`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum). To make the item editable you have to do: `ui->tableWidget_1->item(row,col)->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsSelectable|Qt::ItemIsEnabled|Qt::ItemIsEditable);`

Comment: If you set `~(Qt::ItemIsSelectable|Qt::ItemIsEnabled)`, you may set any flag except the two - hence the item isn't enable anymore (nor selectable). This is probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Item flags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum) are just bits of an integer number. To set or unset a flag, you need to get that number:

```
auto currentFlags = ui->tableWidget_1->item(row,col)->flags();
```

and write one or zero respectively to desired position, leaving other bits untouched. For example, to enable editing you can do the following:

```
auto currentFlags = ui->tableWidget_1->item(row,col)->flags();
ui->tableWidget_1->item(row,col)->setFlags(currentFlags | Qt::ItemIsEditable‌);
```

Analogically, this code disables editing:

```
auto currentFlags = ui->tableWidget_1->item(row,col)->flags();
ui->tableWidget_1->item(row,col)->setFlags(currentFlags & (~Qt::ItemIsEditable‌));
```

Bitwise oring allows you to set more than one flag at once. Your example works because setting `Qt::ItemIsSelectable|Qt::ItemIsEnabled` leaves zero at `Qt::ItemIsEditable‌` flag's position, as it leaves zeros everywhere except specified flags. `setFlags` does not raise more flags to one, it just completely overwrites all flags with specified ones.

And this is not only how flags work in Qt, it's how bitwise operations work in C++ in general. Most APIs (including Qt) just use this behavior to implement flags abstraction.

Answer (score 13):

Sergey's answer is usually what people do, but there's also an alternative with Qt.

Qt wraps enum flags in the [`QFlags`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qflags.html) class template. This happens automatically for enums defined by Qt.

You can use the [`setFlag()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qflags.html#setFlag) function to set and unset individual flags:

```
auto item = item(row, col);
auto flags = item->flags();
flags.setFlag(Qt::ItemIsEnabled, false).setFlag(Qt::ItemIsSelectable, false);
item->setFlags(flags);
```

`setFlag()` can be chained (as can be seen in the example) since it returns a reference to the flags object. So you can write something like:

```
item->setFlags(item->flags()
    .setFlag(Qt::ItemIsEnabled, false)
    .setFlag(Qt::ItemIsSelectable, false));
```

Which is shorter, but still a bit verbose, which is why some people stick to the bit-wise operators to manipulate the flags (which are [bit masks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing))) directly. But using `setFlag()` is a good option that you might find more readable.